# Update Maven project internal error - ReferencedComponentXMIResourceImpl cannot be cast to JptXmlResource

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-kepler

I need some help from Eclipse/Maven experts out there - I am unable to see my project as a resource to deploy to Tomcat within Eclipse.  So I did a search and found that if I run Maven-->Update Project, that would alleviate the problem.  However, updating resulted in the following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.impl.ReferencedComponentXMIResourceImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jpt.common.core.resource.xml.JptXmlResource
```

I have no idea what the problem could be.

Comment: I fixed my own problem.  Essentially the problem was there was something missing in my persistence.xml file (ns tag at the top).  I recreated the entire project by copying source files into another folder, nuking the eclipse project and then recreating the project from the pom.  After that, I fixed the persistence.xml project and it worked fine.  Rather misleading error message and took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: Any chance you can pull that out into an answer? If you write it out enough to make it useful for others later, then this question can be a valuable resource all around.

Answer (score 12):

I could handle the problem by disable the active Java EE configurator 'JPA Configurator' under:
Preferences -> Maven -> Java EE Integration -> Select active Java EE configurators -> disable *'JPA Configurator'*

I am using eclipse Luna with m2e 1.5.0.20140606-0033.

Comment: i was importing an existing maven project into eclipse luna workspace. and above answer solve the problem. thanks.

Comment: I was having the same issue in my existing project. After restarting eclipse, it has been resolved.

Comment: For me it was also a false positive that was worked around by a eclipse restart ...

Comment: It is working on Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0) Build id: 20200615-1200