# Cannot import existing Maven projects - Broadleaf

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, broadleaf-commerce

I'm trying to setup Broadleaf in my local machine, I'm following the getting started guide and I'm having an error on the step when I import existing Maven projects in eclipse Juno, I get the following error

> An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".
>   org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.impl.ReferencedComponentXMIResourceImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.resource.xml.JpaXmlResource

I tried to Google it but the only info I could get was this but wasn't helpful

[Update Maven project internal error - ReferencedComponentXMIResourceImpl cannot be cast to JptXmlResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442348/update-maven-project-internal-error-referencedcomponentxmiresourceimpl-cannot)

Please help.

Comment: Juno is a fairly old Eclipse release (from 2012); any reason you can't use Luna (2014) or at least Kepler (2013)?

Comment: I was getting another error with Luna, will try again and post the error I get here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a work around. I Downloaded Eclipse Luna, then I ran `mvn compile` on the root pom from terminal, then I went back to eclipse to import existing Maven projects. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution posted to solve this cast exception in Eclipse Juno,

post here: [Update Maven project internal error - ReferencedComponentXMIResourceImpl cannot be cast to JptXmlResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21442348/update-maven-project-internal-error-referencedcomponentxmiresourceimpl-cannot)

by disabling the JPA Configurator in eclipse preferences,

Preferences -> Maven -> Java EE Integration -> Select active Java EE configurators -> disable 'JPA Configurator'

It worked for me. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Maven Parents Folder in Package Explorer, goto DemoSite - > Right Click -> Maven -> Update Project. Then Import the project. Will work fine.